# How to bind the count of items in a grouped listview by some kind of criteria in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

***This is what I want***

[image: This is what I want]

***This is what I have now***

[image: This is what I have now]

***The difference is the numbers on the header of each group.***

I am working on building an instant messaging software using WPF. In the above screenshot you can see the contact list. They are grouped by the relationship with me in a listview control. On the header of each group, it shows the group name (James Family, Friends) and the people who are online and total number of the members in the group. e.g. 0/2 means 0 contacts out of 2 are online. 1/1 means 1 contact is online and the group only has 1 contact. Now I can bind the group name(Binding Path = Name) and the total number of members in the group (Binding Path = ItemCount) in xaml, but fail to bind the number of the contacts who are online.

Can anyone help?

The contact class looks like below

```
public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private string groupname;
    private bool isOnline;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string Groupname
    {
        get { return groupname; }
        set { groupname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Groupname"); }
    }

    public bool IsOnline
    {
        get { return isOnline; }
        set { isOnline = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsOnline"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The list's xaml

```
                    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactSourceView}" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" Foreground="#FFC7C7C7"/>
                                                        </DockPanel>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Expander.Content>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                    </Expander.Content>
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: do you want your list view looks like the image or, it's actually like it?

Comment: You should post the entire code, the XAML and the ViewModel AKA the one with `ItemCount` property.

Comment: I've posted entire code. ItemCount is not a property of a ViewModel, it's the property of CollectionViewGroup.

Comment: Type of ContactSourceView is Contact?,

Comment: Can you add the code of the view model, where you are binding listview ItemsSource to ContactSourceView,

Answer (score 0):

The first part is simple, you have the `Items` property of the `CollectionViewGroup`, and you have to count how many of them are online, this is done using a converter:

```
public class ContactsToOnlineContactsCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int onlineContacts = 0;
        IEnumerable<object> groupItems = value as IEnumerable<object>;

        foreach (Contact contact in groupItems)
        {
            if (contact.IsOnline)
                onlineContacts++;
        }

        return onlineContacts;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The online contacts TextBlock uses the above converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource ContactsToOnlineContactsCountConverter}}" />
```

Now the problem is that a Contact can change its online status after the groups are generated and the binding above does not get notified. A solution could be to call the `Refresh` method on `CollectionView` when a contact changes its online status.